# Getting [current-page:title] in webform hidden field from panels

Tags: 7, webforms, panels, tokens

Using page manager panels, I created a custom page that populates info taken from several content types. On that page, I have a webform block (created from the original webform content type). 
I need to get the page title in a hidden field that would be used as a email subject in the form parameters.

The `[current-page:title]` token does not return anything, I get a blank email subject. 
To test out what happens I tried to use that token in regular text field as a default value: same result. However, the `[current-page:url]` token does work.

Configuration is :

- Webform 7.x-4.14
- Panels 7.x-3.9
- Page manager 7.x-1.11
- Token 7.x-1.7